# RailsActive Record and Nested Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like for click action on a button to result in the addition of a resource to a join table. There are several ways to do this in the console but I can't for the life of me figure out how to implement this outside the console.

Here is an example that mimics my current model:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reports
  has_many :schools, through: :reports
end

class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reports
  has_many :students, through: :reports

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :reports
end

class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :school

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :student
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :school

  validates :student_id, presence: true
  validates :school_id, presence: true
end
```

This method returns all the report cards that belong to a student (student already exists in 
my database):

```
@student.reports
```

This method returns all the schools that a student has attended:

```
@student.schools
```

I can add/associate an existing school to a student by doing this:

```
@school = School.find(params[:id])
if student.present?
@student = Student.find(params[:id])
@student.schools << @school
```

Please note that the association of a single report to many students is intentional. My question now is how do I enable a student to add a school to their report simply by clicking on a particualr  school? My reports table (which basically is a join table) should be automatically updated as soon as this click_action takes place/happens (that is a new row that associates that particular student_id with that particular school id should be created).

Been trying to figure it out but not making progress for some reason.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to start with, in your view you should have a javascript/DOM event for each school:

```
onclick(window.location.href = "<%= path_to_add_school_to_students(student,school) %>")
```

So there you have your one click.

In your controller

```
student=Student.find(params[:student])
if student.schools.find(params[:school]).nil? # if school not already assigned
    student.reports.create(:school_id => params[:school])
end
```